# C# WinForms child form not getting redrawn after Show()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on a C# WinForms app, and I want it to be able to pop open a non-modal dialog which will get redrawn and be interactive at the same time as the main window/form.

The main window is using a SerialPort and displaying data transfer counts, which are continually increasing via a SerialDataReceivedEventHandler.

I can use ShowDialog() which seems to work in a modal fashion, but the main window data counters freeze while the dialog is in use, and I think eventually the serial buffers are overrun.

I think I want to use Show(), but if I do this the dialog appears on screen half-drawn, then is not drawn or interactive any more (gets trashed if I drag another window across it). It stays onscreen until I close the main app window.

Perhaps I should be starting another thread or, likely, am just doing something wrong. I don't usually do C# or Windows programming (maybe you can tell.)

Edit after comments (thanks, commenters):

I think maybe most things are getting run under whatever thread the serial receive event handler gets called under. When starting up my app I create a class to handle the serial, which includes:

```
com.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialRxHandler);
```

The only code that I have written to care about threads is some functions to update the counters and log listbox, which I found had to be wrapped with some InvokeRequired to stop me getting complaints about thread switching:

```
delegate void SetCountDelegate(TextBox tb, int count);
internal void SetCount(TextBox tb, int count) {
    // thread switch magic
    if (InvokeRequired) {
        BeginInvoke(new SetCountDelegate(SetCount), new object[] { tb, count });
    } else {
        tb.Text = String.Format("{0}", count);
    }
}
```

So maybe I shouldn't be trying to Show() a form on this thread. Another InvokeRequired block, or should I be doing things completely differently?

Comment: can you please post your code. are you reading from the Serial port on the UI Thread?

Comment: You're right about needing to use `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`, but you probably shouldn't be trying to update the UI from multiple threads. Can you post your code so we can see what's causing your application to freeze up? You may need to spin the serial port access off onto a separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose I'll answer myself..

Prompted by commenters and a bit of thinking, I did an Invoke() to switch to the UI thread before trying to create and Show() my child dialog. That worked.